# Name for commercial song which becomes accepted as folk song?

Tags: terminology, folk

Is there a term for a commercial song, in a folk/roots style, which gets accepted as an authentic folk original ?

I'm thinking of a song like [The Wheel of the Wagon is Broken](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/The_Light_Crust_Doughboys:The_Wheel_Of_The_Wagon_Is_Broken).

Country/Western Swing fans may know
the version by [Patsy Montana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvPqsx2GlWs).
Likewise Roy Rogers, Milton Brown, Sons of the Pioneers....

People of the WW2 generation, or fans of 1930s dance bands may know the versions
by ["Arthur Young", the street singer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOkY0v9LN80),
[Joe Loss & Orchestra, vocal Chick Henderson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odhgNl31Sg4),
[Rossini's' accordion band](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B2yz6RG334)

But there are more rootsy versions also, for example [Caribou Bill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KsfqtQRbok).

Being accepted as a folk original means that performers feel free to embroider the various loose ends in the lyric
with their own added verses, like you would with a folk song :

for example , Caribou Bill adds a verse addressed to "Old Faithful", the horse:

> So long, Old Faithful
> We've crossed the great divide
> So long, old Faithful
> there's other trails to ride

or Arthur Young, who adds more detail about the "old grey mare":

> The old grey mare is missing
> and there's weeds round the old ranch door
> The wheel of the wagon is broken
> It ain't a-gonna turn no more

The song's composer [Michael Carr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Carr_(composer)) is an interesting topic in himself,
likewise the co-credited composers [Elton Box and Desmond Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_and_Cox_Publications)
who were really the song's publishers. Carr was a resourceful commercial songwriter, working in Denmark Street,
London's "Tin Pan Alley" for many years.

Comment: From the title, I was thinking advertisements, i.e., [*I'd Like to Teach the World to Sing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27d_Like_to_Teach_the_World_to_Sing_(In_Perfect_Harmony))

Answer (score 2):

In the US, such songs might be entered into a "**Old American Songbook**" (songs predating 1919 are generally considered too old for the **Great American Songbook** where libraries limit themselves to 1919 to 1955.  Songs after that date are sometimes sorted into a "**New American Songbook**")  Otherwise, many commercial songs that have made it into folk song catalogues such as Roud are indistinguishable from other community-built folk songs.

Some examples of such songs in the Roud Index.

> **Oh! Susanna**, Stephen Foster (1848) (Roud Index Number 9614)
>
> **Oh Where Oh Where Has My Little Dog Gone (Der Deitcher's Dog)**, Septimus Winner (1864) (Roud Index Number 15385)